# Dynamic Update Of SetTransparent and Font Size

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Here I am trying to simulate the Notepad, As given Task, So Far I coded

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500,500))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)
        self.control.SetBackgroundColour('black'), self.control.SetForegroundColour('green')
        self.SetTransparent(225)

        #Create Status Bar
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        #Create Menus
        menu1 = wx.Menu()
        menu1.Append(wx.ID_NEW, "&New File...  Ctrl+N", "Create A New File")
        menu1.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open...       Ctrl+O", "Open An Existing File")
        menu1.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "&Save...       Ctrl+S", "Save The File")
        menu1.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "&Save As", "Save The File With Extension Type")
        menuquit = menu1.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Quit...         Ctrl+Q", "Close")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, menuquit)

        menu2=wx.Menu()
        menu2.Append(wx.ID_UNDO, "&Undo... \tCtrl+Z", "Undo Selection")
        menu2.Append(wx.ID_CUT, "&Cut... \tCtrl+X", "Cuts A Selected Part")
        menu2.Append(wx.ID_COPY, "&Copy... \tCtrl+C", "Copy Selection")
        menu2.Append(wx.ID_PASTE, "&Paste... \tCtrl+V", "Paste The Coped Selection")
        menu2.Append(wx.ID_DELETE, "&Delete... \tDel", "Deletes A Selection")
        menu2.Append(wx.ID_REPLACE, "&Replace", "Replaces")
        menu2.Append(wx.ID_SELECTALL, "&Select All... \tCtrl+A", "Selects All")

        menu3=wx.Menu()
        menu3.Append(wx.NewId(), "Word Wrap... F10", "Word Wrap Option")
        menu3.Append(wx.NewId(), "Fonts", "Select Fonts")

        menu4=wx.Menu()
        menu4.Append(wx.ID_HELP, "&Help Topics", "Help Topic")
        menupy = menu4.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About PyPad", "About PyPad")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnPyPad, menupy)

        #creating MenuBar
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        menubar.Append(menu1, "&File")
        menubar.Append(menu2, "&Edit")
        menubar.Append(menu3, "&Format")
        menubar.Append(menu4, "&Help")

        #Set the Menu Bar
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        #Show the Frame
        self.Show(True)

    def OnPyPad(self, e):
         dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A Text Editor With wxPython.", "About Sample Editor",wx.OK)
         dlg.ShowModal()
         dlg.Destroy()
    def OnQuit(self, e):
         self.Close()        

app = wx.App(True)
frame = MyFrame(None, "Py Editor")
app.MainLoop()
```

Now, Here I was Asked To Create the Dialog Box, when clicked on Help, which I did, now How Am I supposed To Dynamically update the transparency? and Also Make the fonts Bigger, maybe some font properties. :S

Need Some help, Please Do Note That This is just a simulator That has to be done, The menus added are just for display purpose, I am allowed to add as many menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set transparency of the dialog, you'll need to call its SetTransparency method and pass it an amount between 0 and 255. I wrote a tutorial on this [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/04/14/doing-a-fade-in-with-wxpython/). I also wrote a [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/04/28/wxpython-learning-to-use-fonts/) on fonts in wxPython that should tell you how to change the font. Basically you just call the widget's SetFont method and then possibly the Layout() method of the widget's parent to make the changes show up.

Comment: Thumbs up Mike, that helped ... Can you help me with one stuff.. I am trying to pass value from one wx.TextCtrl to another wx.TextCtrl box, now how to refresh the second box. like when a button a clicked. I am using AppendText to pass. Any directions to my this point would be appreciated, and ud save my day. and the second box where I am passing has the readonly attribute.

Comment: You can also use myTextBox.SetValue("")